# Import Label Encorder sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am getting below error when running the code :-

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncorder
LabelEncoder_X = LabelEncorder()
mod_set[:,0] = labelencorder_X.fit_transform(mod_set[:,0])


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5d65523a64f6> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncorder
      2 LabelEncoder_X = LabelEncorder()
      3 mod_set[:,0] = labelencorder_X.fit_transform(mod_set[:,0])

ImportError: cannot import name 'LabelEncorder' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' (/Users/kenilpatel/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/__init__.py)
```

I tried reinstalling scikit as well as updating conda , but nothing seems to work.The problem is with Encorder only , Imputer and other things work fine .

Comment: `LabelEncorder` => `LabelEncoder`: Remove 1 letter `r`

Answer (score 1):

You got a spelling mistake in your module import: `LabelEncorder` => `LabelEncoder`

```py
# from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncorder
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
```